# I output a sound file, but the sound is not added to the wav file

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, csv, wav

Using the terminal on a mac, I output a continuous sound source with 0.3 second increments whose frequency is the value written in the csv file on the desktop, but there is no sound in the output audio file.　I looked at the waveform in Audacity and nothing was recorded, so it does not appear to be a problem on the playback device.

source code in python as below:

```
pip install numpy scipy pydub pandas

import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import pandas as pd
from pydub import AudioSegment

# Path of the CSV file
csv_path = '/Users/username/Desktop/filename.csv'

# Read the CSV file
data = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

# Extract the columns of values
values = data['column name'].values.

# Set sampling rate and time
sample_rate = 44100 # Sampling rate (Hz)
duration = 0.3 # Length of each sound (seconds)

# Audio generation
audio = AudioSegment.empty()
for value in values:.
    frequency = float(value)
    t = np.linspace(0, duration, int(duration * sample_rate), endpoint=False)
    waveform = np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency * t)
    audio += AudioSegment(
        waveform.astype(np.int16).tobytes(), sample_width=2, channels=1, frame_rate=sample_rate
    )

# Output file name
output_path = '/Users/username/Desktop/output.wav'

# Export audio file
audio.export(output_path, format='wav')
```

```
python /Users/username/Desktop/filename.py
```

→No error message is displayed, but no sound is added to the wav file.

I would be grateful for your help.

additional information:
machine: MacBook Pro
CPU: Apple M2 Pro
OS: macOS Ventura 13.5.2
version: Python 3.10.4

Answer (score 0):

Your waveform will all be numbers between -1 and 1. When you convert your waveform to int16 values then will all get rounded (all going to 0). You should multiply the waveform by 32767 ([the maximum range of an int16](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.01-understanding-data-types.html#NumPy-Standard-Data-Types)) before converting it to int16 and see if that works.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped, please mark it as accepted and up vote it.